# Shake Detection - IBM Worklight 6.1 Android Plugin

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, hybrid-mobile-app

I am developing a Shake Detection Project in IBM Worklight 6.1 targeting Android and IOS platforms. 
I followd this: http://androidexample.com/Accelerometer_Basic_Example_-_Detect_Phone_Shake_Motion/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=109&aaid=131

Based on the following link: [Android – Using native pages in hybrid applications](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/06_04_Android_-_Using_native_pages_in_hybrid_applications.pdf)

I need to generate a plugin first, then i need to call that plugin from Javascript function.

I need to know which function i can call from Javascript, so that in turn it will call the android plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Learn to create Cordova plug-ins in Worklight and how to call them.
This is explained in the Creating Cordova plug-ins training modules with accompanying sample projects.

[Adding native functionality to hybrid apps with Cordova](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#cordova). Specifically:

- iOS – Adding native functionality to hybrid application with Apache Cordova plugin
- Android – Adding native functionality to hybrid application with Apache Cordova plugin

---

Maybe you could use the Cordova Accelerometer API to detect a fast motion like a shake, and if detected then execute your plug-in there via JS: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.1.0/cordova_accelerometer_accelerometer.md.html#Accelerometer

Comment: I am familiar with Adding native functionality to hybrid apps with Cordova. My doubt is, we have call the function from javascript, similar like greetMe() in the IBM Training Module. You are calling that greet me when clicking the submit button. In my case, i have to declare it globally, so that the function will call the plugin whenever we shaking the device. But even i am calling it globally, it is not triggering the shake plugin. I need to know which how do i call the JavaScript function, so that it will trigger the shake detection plugin.

Comment: Maybe you could use the Cordova Accelerometer API to detect a fast motion like a shake, and if detected then execute your plug-in there via JS: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.1.0/cordova_accelerometer_accelerometer.md.html#Accelerometer